# Inverse Z transform of $\dfrac{2(z^2-5z+6.5)}{(z-2)(z-3)}$, for $2<\left|z\right|<3$

Tags: inverse

I want to find inverse $\mathcal{Z}$ transform of

$\dfrac{2(z^2-5z+6.5)}{(z-2)(z-3)}$ valid on an annulus region for example for $2<\left|z\right|<3$

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the inverse $z$-transform in general?

Comment: Yeah, I know . I saw that Z transforms is defined(unilateral) for a function f(n), only when $n\geq 0$, in that case in this problem there won't be any contribution of $(z-3)$

Comment: I left an answer @Reg. Makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\dfrac{2(z^2-5z+6.5)}{(z-2)(z-3)}=2-\frac{1}{z-2}+\frac{1}{z-3}$$
we can make it more clear as 
$$2-\frac{z^{-1}}{1-2z^{-1}}+\frac{z^{-1}}{1-3z^{-1}}$$

Now consider the given ROC, and the [table of inverse $z$-transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform#Table_of_common_Z-transform_pairs), and notice that $\mathcal{Z}^{-1}\{z^{-k}X(z)\}=x[n-k]$ to find the inverse $z$-transform.